# postgresql trigger causing Recursion

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update

Here is the table :

```sql
drop table SC;
CREATE TABLE SC(
    Sno char(6) NOT NULL,
    Cno char(6) NOT NULL,
    Grade int
);

INSERT INTO SC VALUES('95001','1',92);
INSERT INTO SC VALUES('95001','2',80);
INSERT INTO SC VALUES('95002','1',Null);
INSERT INTO SC VALUES('95002','2',71);
INSERT INTO SC VALUES('95002','3',52);
```

I want to write a trigger which will work when **If the failed grades are modified, a prompt message will be given and the operation will be cancelled.**

Here is the trigger

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION QUESTION2FUNC() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
 BEGIN
  if (old.grade<60 ) then -- failure
  raise
  EXCEPTION 'Can"t update';
  return null;
  elsif (old.grade>=60) then
 update sc set grade = new.grade where sno = old.sno;
  RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  end;
 $BODY$ language plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER QUESTION2 AFTER
UPDATE
    ON SC
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE QUESTION2FUNC()
```

causing a recursion mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE
 FUNCTION QUESTION2FUNC() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
  BEGIN
   if (old.grade<60 ) then
   raise
   EXCEPTION 'Can"t update';
   return null;
   else -- directly return new, without update again.
   return new;
   END IF;
   end;$BODY$ language plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER QUESTION2 AFTER
UPDATE
    ON SC
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE QUESTION2FUNC()
```